# Access many2many field values before saving to database in clean method django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have the below model and I am trying to raise a validation error in clean method based on the values of many2many field

```
RULE_SET_CHOICES = (
    ('G', 'GLOBAL'),
    ('C', 'LOCAL')
)

class Books(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=RULE_SET_CHOICES, null=False, default='C')
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name="books", blank=True, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.type = 'G':
            // Check if type is Global and if we tried to associate / add authors  then raise a validation error 
            if self.author :
                raise ValidationError("When type is global, you should not associate authors")
```

But when I tried to access `self.author` I am facing below error

```
*** ValueError: "<Books: Hello World- G>" needs to have a value for field "author " before this many-to-many relationship can be used
```

So is there any way to access many-2-many relationship field values before saving into database? as I need to raise a validation error based on its values as above

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a model form for validation, you can access the form field in `self.cleaned_data`.

I'm not aware of a way to check the value in the model's `clean` method. You'll have check `self.pk` before accessing the many-to-many field.

```
def clean(self):
    if self.pk and self.type = 'G':
        ...
```

Note that `self.author` is the related manager, so `if self.author` will always be true. Perhaps you want `self.author.exists()`. Since there can be more than one author, it would be better to name the field `authors`.