# Django: how to access ManyToManyField assignments before .save() method (during model .clean() method)

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

## Background

### Goal

I have a Model that needs to be associated with different objects depending on its type, so I'm validating this in the Model's `.clean()` method. If it's a "Dialogue" type, then it should only have "`dialogue`" objects (`ForeignKeyField`) associated with it. If it's a "Mixed" type, then it should only have "`mixed_chunk`" (`ManyToManyField` with a `through` model) objects associated with it.

### Problem

However, I'm running into issues validating the `ManyToManyField` ("`mixed_chunks`") because the relationship cannot be accessed before the object is saved and receives an id.

With the code below, when I test in the Admin and try to save a `"D"` type `Evaluation` object without attaching any `mixed_chunks` objects (this is done through an inline in the Admin), the conditional `if self.mixed_chunks` in my custom `.clean()` method for the `Evaluation` model evaluates as true even though I haven't selected any `mixed_chunks` objects, therefore raising my validation error `raise ValidationError(_("Only dialogues allowed to be attached for a 'Dialogue'-type eval"))`.

### Things I've tried

I've tried to print some things out to see what is going on:

- when I have selected some `EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo` objects

  - `print(self.mixed_chunks)` = "evaluations.MixedEvalChunk.None"
  - `print(self.e_eval_mixed_chunk_combos)` = "evaluations.EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo.None"
- when I have **not** selected some EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo objects

  - `print(self.mixed_chunks)` = "evaluations.MixedEvalChunk.None"
  - `print(self.e_eval_mixed_chunk_combos)` = "evaluations.EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo.None"
- when I have selected a `dialogue` object

  - `print(self.dialogue)` = the name of the dialogue object
- when I have **not** selected a `dialogue` object

  - `print(self.dialogue)` = "None"

This tells me that the object is not yet associated with the `ManyToManyField` objects that I'm assigning to it in the admin at the time I hit "submit" on the form. How can I perform validation if they aren't accessible when the `.clean()` method is called? If the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052441/access-many2many-field-values-before-saving-to-database-in-clean-method-django) is correct, then it looks like there isn't a way.

**I tried calling `self.save()` in my `.clean()` method but the print results above were exactly the same**

I also don't think it has something to do with the admin itself because this happens no matter how I try to create a new `Evaluation` object.

## Code

#### models.py

```py
from scenario.models import Dialogue

class MixedEvalChunk(models.Model):
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    # bunch of other fields...

class EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo(models.Model):
    eval = models.ForeignKey(
        'Evaluation',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="e_eval_mixed_chunk_combos"
    )
    mixed_eval_chunk = models.ForeignKey(
        MixedEvalChunk,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="m_eval_mixed_chunk_combos"
    )

class Evaluation(models.Model):
    class EVAL_TYPES(models.TextChoices):
        D = 'D', _('Dialogue')
        S = 'S', _('Simultaneous')
        T = 'T', _('Translation')
        M = 'M', _('Mixed')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=EVAL_TYPES.choices, default='D')

    dialogue = models.ForeignKey(
        Dialogue,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    mixed_chunks = models.ManyToManyField(
        MixedEvalChunk,
        blank=True,
        through=EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo
    )

    def clean(self):
        if self.type == 'D':
            if self.mixed_chunks:
                raise ValidationError(_("Only dialogues allowed to be attached for a 'Dialogue'-type eval"))
        elif self.type == 'M':
            if self.dialogue:
                raise ValidationError(
                    {"dialogue": _("Only MIXED EVAL CHUNKS allowed to be attached for a 'Mixed'-type eval"),}
                )
```

#### admin.py

```py
class MixedEvalChunkInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Evaluation.mixed_chunks.through
    extra = 0

@admin.register(MixedEvalChunk)
class MixedEvalChunkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo)
class EvalMixedEvalChunkComboAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["""bunch of stuff.."""]
    fieldsets = ["""bunch of stuff.."""]

@admin.register(Evaluation)
class EvaluationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = ["""bunch of stuff.."""]
    inlines = (MixedEvalChunkInlineAdmin,)
```

Answer (score 0):

First: `if self.mixed_chunks:` doesn't evaluate to `False`, because `mixed_chunks` returns a related manager, *not a queryset*. You still have to ask it to query something, like `.exists()` or `.all()`, for your conditional check to work against the data as intended.

Try `if self.mixed_chunks.exists():` and see if that resolves your other issues with validation.

**Update**:

Given your error message:

> <object> needs to have a value for field “id” before this many-to-many relationship can be used

...the issue you're running into is a bit clearer. Reverse relationships emit additional queries when accessed (or when prefetched explicitly). They do need a primary key to exist before any foreign keys can reference them - including those in many-to-many relationships.

By definition, your `Evaluation` records are allowed to exist independently of their `mixed_chunk` relationships. It's not the `Evaluation` model that needs to be responsible for the validation of the many-to-many data - it's the `EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo` model.

Try putting the `clean()` method on the `EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo` instead. Note that I've renamed the field to `evaluation`, because `eval` is a Python built-in and should be avoided as a variable name:

```py
class EvalMixedEvalChunkCombo(models.Model):
    def clean(self):
        if self.evaluation.type == 'D':
            raise ValidationError
        ...
```

*Other comments*:

- Avoid variable names that are Python keywords, like `type` and `eval`. If there's not a more appropriate name, append an underscore to avoid clobbering (e.g., `type_`).
- Instead of hardcoding the values of `TextChoices` in `if` conditions, you can reference the class directly: `if x == EVAL_TYPES.D:`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I got the same error message: **<object> needs to have a value for field “id” before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**

Comment: I see - would you update your question with the error feedback you've posted in your comment? That would help myself and others better troubleshoot in the future. I will update my answer.